# Prominent Spanish Language Rabbinic Works

Tags: language

Does anyone know of any Jewish religious works written in Spanish or Ladino by a prominent Jewish scholar (eg, Ibn Ezra, etc.)?

Comment: Matthew Miller, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing that comes to mind is the [Me'am Lo'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me%27am_Lo%27ez), by R' Yaakov Culi. It's a commentary on the Bible written in Ladino. In the course of commentary, it ranges widely into exposing all areas of Torah.

There's an English translation called [The Torah Anthology](http://www.judaism.com/display.asp?etn=BDAFH), by R' Aryeh Kaplan.

Comment: Many moons ago, Alex commented on a since-deleted answer that if someone would like to find it online, they can search on hebrewbooks.org for מעם לועז. Currently (as of 2010 - SJ) they've got there the volumes for Bereishis, Shemos (2 vol.), Devarim (vol. 1), and Yehoshua.

Answer (score 5):

The Library of Congress has a [large catalog](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/toc/becites/ladino/63062107a.html) of works written in Ladino, many of which were written by prominent scholars. It might take a while to sift through the database, as there is *a lot* of material there.

Answer (score 3):

Matthias Lehmann's [book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=kljEwsAIhxYC) on Ladino rabbinic literature might be a good place to start... He discusses the context and history of *mussar* literature (writings on Jewish ethical and spiritual development) in Ladino. It looks like many of the works he discusses are translations from Hebrew.

And I second the "vote" for the Me'am Lo'ez! It is my favourite commentary to learn Pirqei Avoth with. By the way, it was started by R. Culi, but he unfortunately died in the middle of his commentary on Exodus. The project was completed by other contemporary rabbis, including Yitshaq Magriso, Yitshaq Agruiti, and Rahamim Mitrani.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Menashe ben Yisra'el.

Here's one of his works in Spanish:
[De la Fragilidad Humana y Inclinacion del Hombre al Peccado](http://cf.uba.uva.nl/en/collections/rosenthaliana/menasseh/1865f2/index.html)

And, here's a web page of his works in general:
[Menashe ben Yisra'el Collection](http://cf.uba.uva.nl/en/collections/rosenthaliana/menasseh/collectie.html)

Answer (score 2):

The book *Puerta Del Cielo* by [Abraham Cohen de Herrera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Cohen_de_Herrera) is an influential Kabbalistic work written in Spanish (it is also available in Hebrew translation as [שער השמים](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/42281)).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but there are apparently a few words of Spanish in the [Zohar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zohar#Modern_criticism.2C_view_of_authorship).

Comment: Boy would I like some more information on the "suspicious traces of Spanish words and sentence patterns" attested in your linked article. See here for another interesting layer of suspicion: http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/AID/663169/ShowFeedback/true

Comment: @WAF I'll bet you can get Scholem's book in your local university library.