# Translating Hebrew works into English

Tags: translation

I hope this is not a stupid question. But, I've seen countless Hebrew works that have yet to be translated into English (I don't know about other languages, like German, French, etc. because I'm not consistently exposed to those languages). These works could be grammars, philosophy, midrashim, etc.

Why are there so many Hebrew works that have yet to be translated into English?

Comment: There are also many English books not translated into Hebrew.

Comment: So, basically, just incentive, motivation, and/ or time? Also, some of these Hebrew books are more than a millennium old. In comparison, English is a relatively new language. So, I understand your point, but there's still a bit of a disparity there.

Comment: [There are no stupid questions](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1208/5).

Comment: [My contribution to the cause](http://www.shlomokluger.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it is universally considered valuable to translate every (I also assume you mean old) Hebrew work into English.

First of all, not every Jew speaks English.

Second, virtually every Jew who might have more than a passing interest in such works is trained (or can get some degree of training) in Hebrew.

Third, not every (old) Hebrew work is all that important.

Most *essential* (old) Hebrew works have been translated into English.

English translations exist of the following (not exhaustive):

The Torah
Prophets
Writings (parts of which actually aren't in Hebrew)
Mishnah
Midrash
Talmud Yerushalmi  (not Hebrew, in any case)
Talmud Bavli  (not Hebrew)
Mishneh Torah
Rashi on the Torah
Ramban on the Torah
R' Hirsch on the Torah
Works of Mussar
Works of Halachah
Moreh Nevuchim  (as Double AA pointed out, this was translated *to Hebrew* first, from Arabic)
Works of history
Works of philosophy  (many are not originally in Hebrew)
Many others (originally from Hebrew and other languages, including Arabic, Ladino, and Yiddish)

Comment: Worth noting that the Moreh Nevuchim (chosen from your list) was originally written in Arabic anyway.

Comment: That's true. I deleted [Me'am Lo'ez](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3895/5) from my answer before posting it. I should have deleted that, too.

Comment: Although, to be fair, T"Y and T"B aren't Hebrew either.

Comment: Good enough for me. (Note: Of course, I meant a Jew who spoke both Hebrew and English.) ;) Also, say, one major work of which I am not familiar with an English translation is the Yalkut Shimoni. Correct?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Yalut Shim'oni is basically just a collection of midrashim, most of which have been translated.

Comment: Seth, your phrases of "works of halacha" and "works of mussar" seems to imply that everything in these categories has been translated into English.  The categories are both very broad and the numbers of untranslated volumes within these categories is also broad.  BTW, one rabbi in Israel once quipped to me that the Soncino Talmud ought to be translated into English one day.  "They say it is English, but it reads like Greek, and not very good Greek, either."

Comment: @BruceJames, I did not mean to imply that everything in those categories had been translated, just that there are works in those categories that have been.  As for Soncino, I actually like it. It's about as clear in English as the Gemara itself is in Aramaic (the downside being that the Gemara has Rashi, Tosafoth, and myriad other commentaries, whereas the Soncino has a couple of footnotes at the bottom).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple supplementary answer to Seth's is that translation takes money.  Booksellers have to be able to guarantee a market for a translated book of Jewish learning sufficient to cover the expenses of translating, printing and distribution.  Often that can't be done.  The Mesorah Foundation helps underwrite the original scholarly books and translations produced by Art Scroll, and while they've done amazing things, they don't have enough funds to do all of the great things they want to do.  If you want to see more books translated, you can contribute small amounts, or sponsor an entire book or series, as the Schottenstein family, for example has done.

Also, there is a pressing need to find and republish lost books of learning still in Hebrew, and money is needed for that.